# Lowercase letters that did not appear in the array, in order

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, c-strings

> Define a function that receives an array of characters (and its size), and then prints out all the lowercase letters  that did not appear in the array, in order.
>
> For example:
>
> input: `Article 1: All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.`
> output: `jkpvwxz`

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void missing(char string[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
    }
}

int main(){
}
```

**Question**

*TBD*

Comment: It looks like you forgot to write the code for *your* task.

Comment: This is SO, we shouldn't solve assignment you get, you need to show effort of trying and solve the issue yourself and if you struggle in a certain point than the community come in help; please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you haven't decided on a question yet, there's no need to post is there?

Answer (score 1):

We, beginners, should help each other.

If the function deals with strings then the second parameter of the function is redundant.

A straightforward approach without using standard containers as for example `std::set` can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

void missing( const char s[] ) 
{
    const char *letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for ( size_t i = 0; letter[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( s[j] != '\0' and s[j] != letter[i] ) j++;

        if ( s[j] == '\0' ) std::cout << letter[i];
    }        
}

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {        
        const size_t N = 100;
        char s[N];

        std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";

        if ( not std::cin.getline( s, N ) or s[0] == '\0' ) break;

        missing( s );

        std::cout << '\n';
    }        
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a sentence: Article 1: All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights
jkpvwxz
Enter a sentence:
```